# run winforms application without making login to windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I make windows forms application to be run on windows 7 without forcing user to login?

Comment: Use a `Windows Service` and no `WinForm` application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of a form before user log in? You should write a windows service and a windows form application to interact with it.

[Here is a tutorial to create a windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks. My application have to be a windows forms application. the application connects to RFID reader device and with each RFID sticker paths though the reader antenna field the application should decide to open a gate or  not and the system displays last 10 stickers data and entry time for each one and the user make many other scenarios with the application. Now if computer restarted I want the application to be opened automatically to manage the stickers login to the gate.

Comment: try setting automatic login for your windows account and add the application shortcut to start up folder.

Comment: I am now trying to automatically start a remote session on the computer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As I already mention in the comment, use a `Windows Service`. A `Windows Service` run without any logged on user.

> Services can be set up to start automatically or manually. A service
>   that starts automatically will be started when the computer on which
>   it is installed is rebooted or first turned on. A user must start a
>   service that starts manually. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984431(v=vs.71).aspx))

Have a look at the [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft.